# Integral question - $\int\frac{(x+6)\,dx}{4x-x^2}$

Tags: integration

Integral question - $\int\frac{(x+6)\,dx}{4x-x^2}$
What I did is  $$\int\frac{(x+6)\,dx}{x(4-x)}$$ 
then
$$\int\frac{(x+6)\,dx}{4x-x^2}= \int\left(\frac{A \,}{x}+\frac{B}{4-x}\right) dx$$ 
this is the right way? 
Thanks!

**Addition:** 
$$A(4-x)+B(x)=x+6$$
$$ x=0 , 4A=6 => A=\frac{6}{4} , x=4, 4B=4+6 => B=\frac{10}{4}$$

$$\int\left(\frac{6\,}{4x}+\frac{10}{4(4-x)} \right)dx$$

Comment: So far, so good...

Comment: It looks nice so far...

Comment: Yup, and now it's just a matter of natural logs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you've done a great job, having just learned the partial-fraction technique!

I suspect you can take the integrals from here, and evaluate?

First, you can also simplify the constant terms (divide numerator/denominator by $2$ in each integral), or putting $A = \dfrac 32, \; B = \dfrac 52$, and you remove them from inside the integral (multiply each integral by its respective constant term.)

Comment: well, the answer certainly worked for the OP! :-) +1